# VB6: does "On Error Goto 0" affect the error handler for the calling function?

Tags: vb6, error-handling

If `On Error Goto 0` is called in a VB6 Sub, will this switch off error handling even when control goes back to the calling Function/Sub?

EDIT: If I have output in an error-handler block that is showing an error number of 0, what does that indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The [VB6 manual makes it clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=VS.60).aspx) that `On Error Goto 0` only affects the current procedure:

> `On Error Goto 0` disables any enabled
>   error handler in the current
>   procedure.

**EDIT** There's now an addition to the question, which wasn't there when I posted this answer. The question is "If I have output in an error-handler block that is showing an error number of 0, what does that indicate?". For the answer, see [Mike's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090510/vb6-does-on-error-goto-0-affect-the-error-handler-for-the-calling-function/3094407#3094407)

Answer (score 2):

No.

http://www.vb-helper.com/tut6.htm

```
When a program encounters an error, Visual Basic 
checks to see if an error handler is presently installed 
in the current routine. If so, control passes to that error handler.

If no error handler is in effect, Visual Basic moves
up the call stack to the calling routine to see if
an error handler is currently installed there. If so,
the system resumes execution at that error handler.

If no error handler is installed in the calling routine
either, Visual Basic continues moving up the call stack 
until it finds a routine with an error handler installed. 
If it runs off the top of the stack before it finds an 
active error handler, the program crashes.
```

Comment: Your quote is true enough, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: The answer is "No", the quote is just an explanation (which is basically that an error handler is scoped to a procedure and all called procedures that do not install their own error handler). But I think the quote says it better...

Answer (score 2):

> If I have output in an error-handler block that is showing an error number of 0, what does that indicate?

This means the `Err` object did not contain error information at the point in the code where you checked the `Err.Number` property. This can happen for a number of different reasons:

- The `Err` object has been explicitly cleared by a previous call to `Err.Clear`
- The `Err` object was cleared by calling `On Error Goto`. An `On Error Goto` statement will clear the current `Err` object
- The `Err` object was cleared by a `Resume X` statement. Unlike a normal `Goto X` statement, a `Resume` will clear the current `Err` object (and raise an error of its own if the `Err` object was already empty)
- You forgot to exit the current `Sub`/`Function`/`Property` prior to reaching the error handler, for example:

  ```
  Public Sub SampleRoutine

     On Error Goto ErrorHandler

     DoSomething
     DoSomethingElse

     ' You need an Exit Sub here so that the code does not reach the error handler'
     'in the event no error occurs.'

  ErrorHandler:

     MsgBox Err.Number & "-" & Err.Description

  End Sub
  ```

This is a pretty common mistake in my experience. If you don't explicitly exit the routine before reaching the error handler label, the code in the error handler will still run even when no errors occur. In this case, `Err.Number` will be 0 since no error occurred.